# Error when running mapreduce job from windows client

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in the hadoop world. I have setup a hadoop cluster in Linux and I try to run a mapreduce job from windows.
I wordcount example work find, but when I try to run another job that I wrote myself, I have this error:

```
16/07/05 16:04:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/07/05 16:04:42 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /myIP:8050
16/07/05 16:04:42 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/07/05 16:04:42 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
16/07/05 16:04:42 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
16/07/05 16:04:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
16/07/05 16:04:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1467727275250_0002
16/07/05 16:04:43 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
16/07/05 16:04:43 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1467727275250_0002
16/07/05 16:04:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoopMaster:8088/proxy/application_1467727275250_0002/
16/07/05 16:04:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1467727275250_0002
16/07/05 16:04:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1467727275250_0002 running in uber mode : false
16/07/05 16:04:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/07/05 16:04:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1467727275250_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1467727275250_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1467727275250_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://hadoopMaster:8088/cluster/app/application_1467727275250_0002Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1467727275250_0002_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: /bin/bash: Zeile 0: fg: Keine Job-Steuerung in dieser Shell.

Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: /bin/bash: line 0: fg: no Job control in this Shell.

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

Failing this attempt. Failing the application.

16/07/05 16:04:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

mapred-site.xml add property

```
  <property>
    <name>mapred.remote.os</name>
    <value>Linux</value>
    <description>Remote MapReduce framework's OS, can be either Linux or Windows</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.app-submission.cross-platform</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We appreciate the answer, but it is best to leave comments on why you use the code you posted. Thanks!